# Does Unreal Engine 4.26 support packaging android with pvr texture format?

Tags: android, unreal-engine4, pvrtc

I'm trying to use PVR format when packaging Android for a phone using powervr GPU. But I cannot find the option:

[image]

Where can I enable Android (PVR) when packaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Unreal Engine 4.25 has removed Android PVR texture formats, although [the docs claims that it support PVRTC on Android](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/Mobile/Android/Reference/).

In [UE4.25 release note](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/WhatsNew/Builds/ReleaseNotes/4_25/),

> Deprecated: Removed ATC/ETC1 and Android PVR texture formats.

In the official github repo, the commit that removed PVR is [a745d7eb863aa5ba96b886220253dfdfea3e63ca](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/commit/a745d7eb863aa5ba96b886220253dfdfea3e63ca).